# Pagination adding page-numbers dots when using 'mid_size' => 0

Tags: functions, pagination

*Hey all, I'm attempting to do convert my current pagination:*

- from : `Prev 1 2 3 Next`
- to: `Page 1 of 2 -->`

*My current code looks like this:*

```
if( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) {
    function my_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;    
        $big = 999999999; // This needs to be an unlikely integer
        $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big) ),
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'mid_size' => 0,
            'prev_next' => True,            
            'prev_text' => __('<span class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>'),
            'next_text' => __('<span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>'),
            'type' => 'list'
        ) );
        if ( $paginate_links ) {
            echo '<div class="pagination">';
            echo $paginate_links;
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

*I have had NOT much experience at all dealing with pagination in WordPress until now, that is. I thought I'd make it easy on myself and simply change the_size to 0, then just use CSS before and after to add the `page of`, like so:*

```
.pagination li:first-child:before {
    content: "Page "
}

.pagination li:first-child:after {
    content: " of"
}
```

But then I notice that WordPress is inserting:

```
<li><span class="page-numbers dots">…</span></li>
```

Because of the `'mid_size' => 0`, and obviously I could just use `li:nth(2) { display: none; }` in the CSS. But then another issue is that the last page number is `a href`  which is something I don't want either, so using all these work around methods just seems like a botched job and rather to do in the codex rather than the CSS. I've tried several solutions with no success.

How do I disable the adding of:

- `<span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>`?
- `<a href>` on the last page number?
- Or how do you recommend I proceed altering the current array?

Comment: IIRC the one time I needed to use `paginate_links` I ended in "forking" it. Found it much simpler then figting its assumptions and complexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

First change the `paginate_links()` output type to:

```
'type' => 'array',
```

Then we can collect the *previous*, *current* and *next* parts from the `paginate_links()` output.

Here's a simple example where we target the relevant classes:

```
$next       = '';
$current    = '';
$prev       = '';
foreach( (array) $paginate_links as $link )
{           
    if( false !== strpos( $link, 'prev ' ) )
        $prev = $link;
    elseif( false !== strpos( $link, ' current' ) )
        $current = $link;       
    elseif( false !== strpos( $link, 'next ' ) )
        $next = $link;
}
```

Finally we can construct the output as needed:

```
! empty( $current ) && printf(
    '<div class="pagination">%s %s %s %s %d %s</div>',
    $prev,
    esc_html__( 'Page', 'my-domain' ),
    $current,
    esc_html__( 'of', 'my-domain' ),
    $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    $next
);
```

Comment: Hey @Birgire, this almost works but apart from on pages with results fewer than 1 page results in an error (Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in functions.php on line 26) Here's how I added your code to my current code with the changes you suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/6uLLpomr/

Comment: @SimonHayter, I think we could add an array casting in the foreach loop and a check for non-empty `$current` before printing, to cover that.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you @SimonHayter