# How to custom post navigation

Tags: customization, pagination

I'm not an expert in PHP but would like to customize the pagination of my posts.

Instead of having  : prev 1, 2, 3, 4, next

I would like : Prev  1 of 4   Next

It seems I have to modify my single.php file and these lines :

```
<?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before'  => '<span class="current"><span class="currenttext">', 'link_after' => '</span></span>', 'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', 'nextpagelink' => __('Next', 'sociallyviral' ), 'previouspagelink' => __('Previous', 'sociallyviral' ), 'pagelink' => '%','echo' => 1 )); ?>
```

If you already have made this customization could you help me ?

Thank you very much

Comment: 1 of 4, you mean just at random 1 out of 4?

Comment: No for exemple I write an article like top 10 funny images of cat

Between each image I put <!--nextpage-->

I would like to have "3 of 10" when visitors are in the 3rd image instead of the default numbers

Comment: Hello @vito35 - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! A good question displays research and implementation effort on the asker's behalf - you should add information regarding what you have tried, and why it doesn't work. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more pointers on how to write a quality question.

Comment: Hello @bosco I am not an expert in php as explained above and I tried all the php code I could find and try in stackexchange before asking here.

I modified mu function.php and my single.php file an hundred times.

I am sorry if there isn't enough information as I said before I'm not an expert with PHP.

But regarding to the total amount of people searching for this hack without solution, I think it could help a lot of people :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try combining these:

### Buttons

```
next_posts_link( 'Prev' );
previous_posts_link( 'Next' );
```

### Current page

```
echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

### Total pages

```
wp_count_posts();
```

### In HTML

```
<?php next_posts_link( 'Prev' ); ?>
<?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<span> of </span>
<?php echo wp_count_posts(); ?>
<?php next_posts_link( 'Prev' ); ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, here is the code from you I added : 

`<?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before'  => '<span class="current"><span class="currenttext">', 'link_after' => '</span></span>', 'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', 'nextpagelink' => __('Next', 'sociallyviral' ), 'previouspagelink' => __('Previous', 'sociallyviral' ), 'pagelink' => '%','echo' => 1 )); echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; wp_count_posts(); ?>`

Comment: @vilto35 that's not the code that provided in the answer =/

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden `$wp_query->max_num_posts` will contain the number of navigable pages generated by the query. `wp_count_posts()` counts the number of a certain post type in the database, and returns an object mapping post statuses to counts.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Where I have to add your code ? How I have to format it ? I don't know very well PHP code I'm really sorry :/

Here is a picture of what I Have : !http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/780103pagination.jpg

Here is a picture of what I would like to have :
!http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/787285pagination2.jpg

Comment: @vilto35 Please add all this extra information to your question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we set the content pagination type to `next` with:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_args', function( Array $args )
{
    $args['next_or_number'] = 'next';
    return $args;
} );
```

then we can inject the `x of y` part between the *Previous page* and *Next page* links with:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', function( $link, $nextorprev ) use ( &$page, &$numpages )
{
    if( $nextorprev <= $page || 1 === $page )
        $link .= sprintf( ' %d %s %d ', $page, esc_html__( 'of', 'mydomain' ), $numpages );

    return $link;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Then the output of `wp_link_pages()` would be like:

```
Pages: Previous page 5 of 6 Next page
```

Comment: ps: I first thought you meant for `paginate_links()` where there's [a workaround](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/224620/26350), but that's unrelated to content pagination.