# Getting paginate_links() 'end_size' to display none

Tags: php, pagination, paginate-links

I'm working with the paginate_links() function and I'm trying to create a pagination in this kind of style;

< 3 4 **5** 6 7 >

Logically I thought it would be simple by setting end_size to 0 and mid_size to 2.

I have done this but my code is outputting as this;

< 1 ... 3 4 **5** 6 7 ... 9 >

To me, this is showing the end_size as 1, even though I have it set to 0 (unless I'm misunderstanding what the option does).

My current paginate links function looks like this;

```
$paginationArgs = array(
    'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'        => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
    'end_size'      => 0,
    'mid_size'      => 1,
    'prev_next'     => TRUE,
    'prev_text'     => '<',
    'next_text'     => '>',
    'type'          => 'list',
    'add_args'      => FALSE,
    'add_fragment'  => ''
)
$pagination = paginate_links($paginationArgs);
```

Does anyone have any advice/answers?

Thanks, Harry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one suggestion:

First we need to let `paginate_links()` return an array instead of a HTML list:

```
'type' => 'array',
```

Then we can grab the output with:

```
$paginate_links = paginate_links( $paginationArgs );
```

The plan is then to filter out the wanted links.

Let's get the current value:

```
$c = $paginationArgs['current'];
```

We construct the search filter as:

```
$allowed = [
    ' current',
    'prev ',
    'next ',
    sprintf( '/page/%d/', $c-2 ),
    sprintf( '/page/%d/', $c-1 ),
    sprintf( '/page/%d/', $c+1 ),
    sprintf( '/page/%d/', $c+2 )
];
```

Note that we could refine this around the edges and only filter what's available. It's also possible to make this dynamically depend on the `mid_size` attribute. Here we assume that:

```
'mid_size' => 2,
```

Also note that:

```
'end_size' => 0,
```

means that `end_size` is 1 because of the following check in `paginate_links()` core function:

```
if ( $end_size < 1 ) {
    $end_size = 1;
}
```

Then we filter the allowed paginate links:

```
$paginate_links = array_filter(
    $paginate_links,
    function( $value ) use ( $allowed ) {
        foreach( (array) $allowed as $tag )
        {
            if( false !== strpos( $value, $tag ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Finally we display the outcome:

```
if( ! empty( $paginate_links ) )
    printf(
        "<ul class='page-numbers'>\n\t<li>%s</li>\n</ul>\n",
        join( "</li>\n\t<li>", $paginate_links )
    );
```

Hope you can adjust it to your needs!

Comment: Wow thanks, this worked great. I did have to do a couple of edits just for anyone referencing this in the future;

On this line: `foreach( (arrow) $allowed as $tag )`, the `(arrow)` bit caused it to error (I'm not sure what it's supposed to do but it's working without it.

Also, on the final piece of code the `$page_links` should be `$paginate_links` (or whatever you set your `paginate_links()` function to be).

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: There is one small thing i've just noticed, I missed it in my original question so my bad. The next/previous arrows should go to the first/last page rather than the next/previous pages. Is this an easy change or should I just add them in statically using page 1/max_num_pages?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Thanks for mentioning the typos, I updated the answer  I was just reading about *arrow* functions in javascript but meant to write *array* here ;-) I remember thinking about various workarounds in another `paginate_links()` problem [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224590/pagination-adding-page-numbers-dots-when-using-mid-size-0/224620#224620). but ended up doing  this kind of filtering approach, as it seemed simple to work with. Not sure what you mean exactly regarding the prev/next but adding them statically might work as well.  @HarryFrancis

Comment: Ah, I will make that change to mine also, thanks. It's a nice method as it gives you good options with the output! 

Currently the next/previous links go to the next/previous page from the current one you're on. I'm hoping to get it so they go to first/last page instead.