# Paginate Pages by only showing 3 pages at most

Tags: pagination

I'm trying to use Wordpress paginate function to only show 3 pages at most(client wants it this way) so that when you go up a page it shows the current page you're on and the previous and next page:

[image: This is the result they want]

Unfortunately when I do it I get several pages including the last page:

[image: This is the result I get from my code]

This is my current paginate code, please note the format is like this because I have Tabs that each need to be paged with different queries

```
echo '<div id ="nav_pages">'; 
    echo '<div class="prev_first"></div>'; 
    echo '<div class="pages">';
$pag_args1 = array(
'type'         => 'list',
'prev_next'       => False,
'end_size'        => 1,
'add_args'        => false,
'add_fragment'    => '',
'show_all' => false,
'base'         => '' . $url . '?paged1=%#%',                
    'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
    'current' => $paged1,
    'total'   => $get_mining->max_num_pages);

    echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="page_x_of_y2">Page <span>' . $paged1 . '</span> of <span>' . $get_mining->max_num_pages . '</span></div>';    
echo '</div>';
```

Is there anyway I can modify this code to look like the pagination in the first image rather than what it looks like in the second one? Do I need to write a custom paginate function to achieve this? I dont agree with what the client wants as I feel like the latter is a better option but you know what they say: "The customer is always right"

### **UPDATED PARTIAL SOLUTION**

So after doing bit more reseach I found this link:[Getting paginate_links()'end_size' to display 0](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237753/getting-paginate-links-end-size-to-display-none)
This solution almost allows me to achieve the goal I want here is my modified code:

```
echo '<div id ="nav_pages">'; 
    echo '<div class="prev_first"></div>'; 
    echo '<div class="pages">';
$pag_args1 = array(
'type'         => 'array',
'prev_next'       => False,
'end_size'        => 0,
'mid_size'        => 1,
'add_args'        => false,
'add_fragment'    => '',
'show_all' => false,
'base'         => '' . $url . '?paged1=%#%',                
    'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
    'current' => $paged1,
    'total'   => $get_mining->max_num_pages);
    $paginate_links = paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
    $c=$pag_args1['current'];
    $allowed=[sprintf('/?paged1=%d',$c-1),'current',sprintf('?paged1=%d',$c+1)];
    $paginate_links=array_filter(
        $paginate_links,
    function( $value ) use ( $allowed ) {
        foreach( (array) $allowed as $tag )
        {
            if( false !== strpos( $value, $tag ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

   if( ! empty( $paginate_links ) )
        printf("<ul class='page-numbers'>\n\t<li>%s</li>\n</ul>\n",join( "</li>\n\t<li>", $paginate_links));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="page_x_of_y2">Page <span>' . $paged1 . '</span> of <span>' . $get_mining->max_num_pages . '</span></div>';    
    echo '</div>';


}//Endif
```

This almost achieves what I want, the only problem now is that it wont show the previous page when I go above page 1. I'm getting Closer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to the link in the updated part of my question. Here is the solution to it:

```
echo '<div id ="nav_pages">'; 
    echo '<div class="prev_first"></div>'; 
    echo '<div class="pages">';
$pag_args1 = array(
'type'         => 'array',
'prev_next'       => False,
'end_size'        => 0,
'mid_size'        => 1,
'add_args'        => false,
'add_fragment'    => '',
'show_all' => false,
'base'         => '' . $url . '?paged1=%#%',                
    'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
    'current' => $paged1,
    'total'   => $get_mining->max_num_pages);
    $paginate_links = paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
    $c=$pag_args1['current'];
    $allowed=[sprintf('?paged1=%d',$c-1),'current',sprintf('?paged1=%d',$c+1)];
    $paginate_links=array_filter(
        $paginate_links,
    function( $value ) use ( $allowed ) {
        foreach( (array) $allowed as $tag )
        {
            if( false !== strpos( $value, $tag ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

   if( ! empty( $paginate_links ) )
        printf("<ul class='page-numbers'>\n\t<li>%s</li>\n</ul>\n",join( "</li>\n\t<li>", $paginate_links));
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="page_x_of_y2">Page <span>' . $paged1 . '</span> of <span>' . $get_mining->max_num_pages . '</span></div>';    
    echo '</div>';
```

So what I had to do was:

1. Make the pagination arguments into an array
2. Store the resultant Array in a variable and store the current page in a variable
3. Create another variable with allowed values, in this case its the current page and a page up and down on either side.
4. Filter the array with a function that allows only the allowed values
5. Finally display the pagination array if there are pages to display.

My solution looks like this now:

[image: Solution I wanted and achieved]

Comment: Great you could solve it. I posted an alternative using only CSS to hide the element, in case you are ok simply doing so, to avoid having the extra filter loop in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Check the mid_size parameter in [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

> mid_size: How many numbers to either side of current page, but not including current page. Default 2.

So set it to: `'mid_size' => 1`

Also you probably don't want to show the first and last page, so set it to 0 (it's 1 by default): `'end_size' => 0`

Hope this helps.

-

EDIT:

It seems like the end property does not hide the last element. The easiest way is to hide it is using CSS:

```
.dots ~ .dots + .page-numbers { display: none; }
```

Otherwise, to remove the actual output from the function you would need to tweak it. You can return an array changing the `type` argument, loop through the elements and remove the one you are not interested in.

Comment: Close but it still shows the last page. 1 2 ... 48 Page 2 0f 48. Thanks for the help im getting closer I just need to not have the last page there.

Comment: @ZaydBhyat Are you sure you set `'end_size' => 0`? It was set to 1 in the question code (make sure it is not twice in the array).

Comment: I’ll double check when I get into work today. I’m pretty sure it’s 0

Comment: My `end_size` has been set to 0 and it is only in the array once. I feel I may need to write a custom function to get this right

Comment: So doing a bit more research i found this on wordpress stackexchange [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237753/getting-paginate-links-end-size-to-display-none). This was the closest for me. Now the only problem is its only showing the next page and not the previous page. @Alvaro can you check the post out and maybe help me what I want to achieve. Ive updated my question to include this source and the my modified code